# insert autotable after each row

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am interested if it's possible to nest/insert another table after each row via JsPDF react library. (please refer to screenshot)
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG7TF.png)